# Face and hair detection for Python

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, face-detection, dlib

I am using `OpenCV` or `dlib` to detect face from images. The result is very good. Here is an example:

[image]

However, I also want to take the hair and the neck from the image, like that:
[image]

I have tried to look for a library or framework to help me achieve that but I can't find one.

Are there any way to do that?

Comment: You need to train your own model for this. As this is out of scope for StackOverflow I'd recommend to post this on either CrossValidated or Data Science page of SO.

Comment: You just need to train a model that instead of considering the face, also cconsiders hair and neck. You can probably use the same face detection library, but you just change the training data.

Comment: try to increase `for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)` **X,Y,W,H**

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to extract exactly region of hair and neck, you need to train your own model because the current dlib model does not include them.

Otherwise, you just want to capture relatively, you can use [Openpose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose) which gives you the landmarks of faces + ears + shoulders (even body and hand fingers). From those landmarks you can draw your interested area.

Example:

the width of rectangle = the length of shoulder (point 2 -> point 5)

the height = the length from the neck to (point 1) to the nose (point 0) x 2. (point 1 - point 0)*2

landmarks by openpose
[image]

face + hair + neck
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this code to increase the bounding box by percentage.

```py
rects = detector(original_image, 1)
for rect in rects:
    (x, y, w, h) = rect_to_bb(rect)
    x_inc = int(w*0.3)
    y_inc = int(h*0.3)
    sub_face = original_image[y-y_inc:y+h+y_inc, x-x_inc:x+w+x_inc]
    newimg = cv2.resize(sub_face,(int(224),int(224)))
```